# Remove elements from list preceded by some specific element

Tags: python, list

Lets say we have a list `[Y, X, 4, Y, 3, X, 2, X]`

I want to be able to remove all elements that are immediately preceded by an X and also remove the X's themselves. So the result should look like `[Y, Y, 3]`. What would be the pythonic way of doing this?

I came up with something like the following, but I feel that it is very clunky and not clean. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
list = [Y, X, 4, Y, 3, X, 2, X]
is_preceded = False
result = []
for i in list:
    if i == 'X':
         is_preceded = True
    elif is_preceded == True:
         is_preceded = False
    else:
         result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = ['Y', 'X', 4, 'Y', 3, 'X', 2, 'X']
>>> [a for a, b in zip(lst, [''] + lst) if b != 'X' and a != 'X']
['Y', 'Y', 3]

# a: current item
# b: previous item
```

By the way, don't use `list` as a variable name. It represents a builtin type/function [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

---

If you use Python 2.x, `zip` will return a new list. If you don't want it use `itertools.izip`.

In addition, if you don't want to create a temporary list (`[''] + lst`), you can use `itertools.chain([''], lst)`.

Comment: Nice, the zip idea is super clever! Also, thanks for the heads up about not using "list" as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend processing the list backwards with list comprehension, like this

```
l = ['Y', 'X', 4, 'Y', 3, 'X', 2, 'X']
rs = [l[i] for i in range(len(l) - 1, 0, -1) if l[i - 1] != 'X' and l[i] != 'X']

if l[0] != 'X':
    rs.append(l[0])

print rs[::-1]
# ['Y', 'Y', 3]
```